# PHP "AT command" not executing on nginx ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, at-job

php sample code Not working on server:

```
exec('echo  "hello world"  | at now + 2 minutes');
```

On terminal same code successfully getting executed below code :

```
echo  "hello world"  | at now + 2 minutes
```

We are using php 7.0, ngnix, ubuntu 16.04 i am able to execute exec("sudo php -v"); successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi We have found the solution you need to remove WWW-DATA (ie. server) from your  `/etc/at.deny` file .